# How to define an end of operator<< method?

Tags: c++, logging, stream, singleton, cout

Thanks to the SO community I have managed to create a simple logger framework. One can use it by `operator<<`, like this:

```
*CLogger::instance(CLogger::ElogLevel::eInfo) << "Application directory " << Enviroment::appDir << "\n";
```

This is the object responsible for gathering input:

```
template<typename T>
    CLogger& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        if (((int)m_logLine.logLevel <= (int)m_userDefinedLogLevel) && m_logStarted)
        {
            ostringstream stream;
            stream << t;
            m_logLine.logString += stream.str();

            if (stream.str().find("\n") != string::npos)
            {
                push_back(m_logLine);
                m_logLine.logString.clear();
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know when did the input gathering of one instance (one method run) finished. As you can see in the code, I have hacked it a little, as it was the only thing I could think of.

The method will finish gathering user input and send the data for printing (`push_back(m_logLine)`) when it will find a `\n` sign. That's why at the moment, I have to finish every log line with `\n` sign. I would like to avoid that as it can be forgotten easily.
Is there any other way to figure out that the stream has been finished?

This is my full code:

CLogger.h:

```
/*
 * CLogger.h
 *
 *  Created on: 25 cze 2015
 *      Author: lukasz
 */

#ifndef CLOGGER_H_
#define CLOGGER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class CLogger
{
public:
    enum class ElogLevel { eNone = 0, eError, eWarning, eInfo, eDebug };

    typedef struct
    {
        string logString;
        ElogLevel logLevel;
    } logline_t;

    static CLogger* instance(ElogLevel ll = ElogLevel::eError);

    bool startLog(string fileName, bool verbose);
    logline_t pop_front();
    void push_back(logline_t s);
    void setLogLevel(ElogLevel ll);

    template<typename T>
    CLogger& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        if (((int)m_logLine.logLevel <= (int)m_userDefinedLogLevel) && m_logStarted)
        {
            ostringstream stream;
            stream << t;
            m_logLine.logString += stream.str();

            if (stream.str().find("\n") != string::npos)
            {
                push_back(m_logLine);
                m_logLine.logString.clear();
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

protected:
    virtual void threadLoop();

private:
    CLogger() {};                               // Private so that it can  not be called
    CLogger(CLogger const&) {};                 // copy constructor is private
    CLogger& operator= (CLogger const&) {};     // assignment operator is private
    static CLogger* mp_instance;
    bool m_logStarted;
    logline_t m_logLine;
    ElogLevel m_userDefinedLogLevel;
    ofstream m_logFileStream;
    bool m_verbose;

    static void * threadHelper(void* handler)
    {
        ((CLogger*)handler)->threadLoop();
        return NULL;
    }

    deque<logline_t> m_data;
    mutex m_mutex;
    condition_variable m_cv;
    pthread_t   thread;
};

#endif /* CLOGGER_H_ */
```

CLogger.cpp:

```
/*
 * CLogger.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 25 cze 2015
 *      Author: lukasz
 */

#include "CLogger.h"

using namespace std;

// Global static pointer used to ensure a single instance of the class.
CLogger* CLogger::mp_instance = NULL;

/** This function is called to create an instance of the class.
    Calling the constructor publicly is not allowed. The constructor
    is private and is only called by this Instance function.
*/
CLogger* CLogger::instance(ElogLevel ll)
{
    //cout << "instance run with logLevel = " << (int)ll << endl;

    // Only allow one instance of class to be generated.
    if (!mp_instance)
        mp_instance = new CLogger;

    mp_instance->m_logLine.logLevel = ll;
    return mp_instance;
}

bool CLogger::startLog(string fileName, bool verbose)
{
    if(remove(fileName.c_str()) != 0)
        perror( "Error deleting file" );

    m_logFileStream.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
    if (!m_logFileStream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Could not open log file " << fileName << endl;
        return false;
    }

    m_verbose = verbose;
    m_logStarted = true;
    return (pthread_create(&(thread), NULL, threadHelper, this) == 0);
}

void CLogger::push_back(logline_t s)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(m_mutex);
    m_data.emplace_back(move(s));
    m_cv.notify_all();
}

CLogger::logline_t CLogger::pop_front()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(m_mutex);
    m_cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return !m_data.empty(); });

    logline_t retVal;
    retVal.logString = move(m_data.front().logString);
    retVal.logLevel = move(m_data.front().logLevel);
    m_data.pop_front();

    return retVal;
}

void CLogger::setLogLevel(ElogLevel ll)
{
    m_userDefinedLogLevel = ll;
}

void CLogger::threadLoop()
{
    logline_t logline;
    const string logLevelsStrings[] = {"eNone", "eError", "eWarning", "eInfo", "eDebug" };

    while(1)
    {
        logline = pop_front();

        uint32_t pos;
        if((pos = logline.logString.find('\n')) != string::npos)
            logline.logString.erase(pos);

        time_t curTime = time(0);
        struct tm* now = localtime(&curTime);

        m_logFileStream << "[" << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" << now->tm_sec << "]"
                << "[" << logLevelsStrings[(int)logline.logLevel] << "] "
                << logline.logString << endl;

        if(m_verbose)
        {
            cout << "[" << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" << now->tm_sec << "]"
                            << "[" << logLevelsStrings[(int)logline.logLevel] << "] "
                            << logline.logString << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an end object and specialize your `operator<<` for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `CLogger::instance()` returns a pointer to a static `CLogger` object. You could change it to return a proxy (by value) which would do finalisation in its destructor. Something like this:

```
struct CLoggerProxy
{
  CLogger &logger;

  CLoggerProxy(CLogger &logger) : logger(logger) {}

  ~CLoggerProxy() { logger.finaliseLine(); }

  template <class T>
  CLoggerProxy& operator<< (const T &t) const
  {
    logger << t;
    return *this;
  }
};

CLoggerProxy CLogger::instance()
{
  return CLoggerProxy(*theInstanceYourOriginalCodeReturned());
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this now, but I dont fully understand it. What exacly do you mean by `logger.finaliseLine();`? What would this method do?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło It adds '\n' to logger

Comment: @Lukasz: It does whatever you wanted to happen when the newline was entered previously- i.e., it flushes the logger.

Comment: I have added full code to my question. I am having problem changing `Clogger::instance()` to compile. It got a bit messy. Could you please take a look and reffer please?

Comment: Basically i get an error that `CLoggerProxy` doesnt name a type.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Simply rename your current `instance` to `internalInstance`, implement a new `instance` as I suggested, and call `internalInstance` from it.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Well, you'll of course have to define `CLoggerProxy` in the proper place so that `CLogger::instance` can see it (possibly also include a forward declaration etc.). But that's standard C++ stuff.

Comment: This c++ basic stuff is not so obvious for me... I cannot get the code to compile. I have got to something like this: This is the .h file https://pastebin.com/iDCzT4uC and here the cpp: https://pastebin.com/JKvxGZEC . I have added the updates but it wont run now. It doesnt compile now because i cant run the inctance as pointer like before, but If I remove the asterix then the `template <class T>` part of CLoggerProxy will fail... `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘CLoggerProxy&’ from expression of type ‘const CLoggerProxy’`. Any hints please?

Comment: @Angew I am trying to run this code for another day now but I still fail. I am getting an error message `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase` when returning from `instance`. Could you please take a look at the code? This is my current example main: https://pastebin.com/32dVrjqN .h: https://pastebin.com/99FpXWVF and .cpp: https://pastebin.com/VWaAzzff

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło There's an awful lot of code unrelated to this question in the pastebins. Get rid of all the thread stuff and make it work on a plain and simple case first (I think it will just work). Ideally isolate some unit tests from it. Then add the threading back, and test it separately. A runtime error during `erase` could be a double-destruction issue, or bad thread synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an `endl` equivalent:

```
struct CLoggerEndl_t { };
static CLoggerEndl_t CLoggerEndl; // or constexpr, in C++11
```

And tell people to use it:

```
*CLogger::instance(CLogger::ElogLevel::eInfo) 
    << "Application directory " 
    << Enviroment::appDir 
    << CLoggerEndl;
```

And provide a special overload for it:

```
CLogger& operator<<(CLoggerEndl_t)
{
    push_back(m_logLine);
    m_logLine.logString.clear();

    return *this;        
}
```

Comment: That's similarly easy to forget as `'\n'`, though.

Comment: I agree with @Angew, but it is fancy though and I have learned something new. Thank you .

Comment: @Angew True, but at least you're not searching for `'\n'`. I guess the real solution is introducing a temporary RAII style. Which is your answer, so I reverted my edit.

Comment: @Barry Which I was writing in parallel to that comment :-)

Comment: @Barry Could you please explain more clearly the second thought?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Just check out Angew's answer.